# how to enable a button in mvc razor based on radio button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code:
In Model:

```
<div class="line"></div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Vehicle.Car, "Car")
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Vehicle.Car)
<div class="clearfix"></div>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Vehicle.Van, "Van")
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Vehicle.Van)
<div class="line"></div> 
<div class=".col-md-6 .col-sm-4  text-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" disabled >submit</button>
</div>
```

I would like to enable the Submit button if either of the radio button is selected. Since using htmlhelper method, not sure of using Jquery method on it. Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: You will need to use JavaScript to read out and manipulate DOM state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in client side. The below example assumes you have jQuery library included in your page.

Assuming your views' view model has a `Vehicle` property which is of type `Vehicle` enum like this

```
public enum Vehicle
{
    None, Car, Van
}
public class CreateUser
{
    public Vehicle Vehicle { set; get; }
    // Other properties as needed
}
```

Give a css class to the radio button and and Id to the submit button for easier jQuery selection.

```
@model YourNamespaceHereForViewModelClass.CreateUser
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{    
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Vehicle, "Car",new {@class="myVehicle"})
    @Html.Label(Vehicle.Car.ToString())

    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Vehicle, "Van", new { @class = "myVehicle" })
    @Html.Label(Vehicle.Van.ToString())

    <button type="button" id="mySubmit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>submit</button>
}
```

and in your script, on the document `ready` event check whether any of the two radio buttons are checked and enable/disable the submit button. Also listen to the `change` event and enable the radio button.

```
$(function () {

    // When the page loads,Check any radio button is checked, If yes enable submit button
    if ($(".myVehicle:checked").length) {
        $("#mySubmit").prop('disabled', false);
    }

    // When user checks a radio button, Enable submit button
    $(".myVehicle").change(function (e) {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#mySubmit").prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });

});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/belahixomu/edit?html,js,output) is a working js fiddle sample.